# C++ - catch all exceptions?

Tags: c++, dll, exception

I want to inject a DLL into a process. Once this DLL is in there, it should catch & properly handle **all** access violation exceptions which occur in the process. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: How do you "properly handle" access violations from an arbitrary process?

Comment: Some compilers allow you to use catch(...) as a catch-all.

Comment: @Chase that doesn't handle access violations. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457577/catching-access-violation-exceptions/918891#918891

Comment: That's not a dupe- that was non-Microsoft, whereas this is going to be Windows-specific.

Comment: @Seth True, it also doesn't handle signals, which if you're trying to make a catch-all type DLL, you'd probably want to consider "catching".

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes not necessarily properly handle, but if for example another injected DLL tries to write to address 0x7FFFFFFF and causes an access violation, I want to stop that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about SetUnhandledExceptionFilter( **function** )?

**function**'s prototype is:

```
LONG __stdcall ExceptionHandler(EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo);
```

I've used this function to create crash dumps, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Structured Exception Handling (SEH) to catch such exceptions. Specifically, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679274%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) Windows function seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: My understanding is SEH catches exceptions in the thread in which the SEH registration happened. When the DLL main runs it can certainly register a handler for access violations (for the thread it was loaded in), but how do you propose it also registers handlers for arbitrary other threads in the process? I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the collection, you can also use [AddVectoredExceptionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Just realized that's what DeadMG posted... VEH != SEH

Answer (score 0):

Pre XP, you cannot catch all exceptions. XP or later, you should use [`AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, handler)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), although you are not guaranteed that you will always be the first vectored exception handler.