# Is AddVectoredExceptionHandler a replacement for SetUnhandledExceptionFilter?

Tags: winapi, exception, seh

[Some resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288222/c-catch-all-exceptions) seem to suggest that instead of using [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to catch unhandled exceptions, one could use [`AddVectoredExceptionHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to be notified of all exceptions.

However, as far as I can understand, a [vectored handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is "just" called for *each and every* (SEH) exception raised in the program, *prior* to determining whether or not or where the exception will be handled.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: It is not, the callback doesn't promise anything about the exception getting handled.  That happens later.  It is, at best, useful as a diagnostic tool to troubleshoot problems with a program that contains too many try/catch-em-all statements.  Compare to the .NET AppDomain.FirstChanceException event, the kind of feature that requires AVEH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good comment:

> It is not [a replacement], the callback doesn't promise anything about the exception getting handled. That happens later. It is, at best, useful as a diagnostic tool to troubleshoot problems with a program that contains too many try/catch-em-all statements. Compare to the .NET AppDomain.FirstChanceException event, the kind of feature that requires AVEH.

–  Hans Passant

---

That being said - and after re-reading the docs I do agree - I think the "confusion", if you will, in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288222/c-catch-all-exceptions) I linked to, may stem from the original question that stated

> it should catch & properly handle all access violation exceptions which occur in the process

which of course you *could* use a vectored exception handler for, that is, you could *intercept* all `0xC0000005` via an VEH, but you'd have no clue whether the code around this may actually catch and handle it -- and, at a low level or for specific cases, catching an Access Violation and continuing at the catch site is a valid approach.

So, as Hans says, it is *at best, useful as a diagnostic tool*.

Or, phrased another way, a Vectored Exception Handler **does NOT catch exceptions**, if you interpret "catching" an exception in the sense the `catch` and [`__except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19.aspx) catch a raised exception at a higher level.

The [`VectoredHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) only supports `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH`: find a handler and `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION`: the use of which I never quite grasped.

Comment: EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXCEPTION is used in the case where you identify the exception, change what caused the problem and then continue execution. Sounds unusual, but there are valid uses for this.