# settings in JVM to ignore JRE error message when the crash happened in native c/c++ code?

Tags: java, c++, c, jvm, java-native-interface

I invoke Java Swing panel from C/C++ application creating JavaVM(). Everything works fine. For any reason if C/C++ crashes then I see the message fatal error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment.The crash happened outside JVM in native code.

Is there any otpion I can set in JVM to ignore errors in native code?. Below is the message.

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xfd933144, pid=29358, tid=1
>
> JRE version: 6.0_22-b04  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
>   (17.1-b03 mixed mode solaris-sparc )  Problematic frame:  C 
>   [libc.so.1+0x33144]  strlen+0x80
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit: 
>   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp  The crash happened
>   outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  See problematic
>   frame for where to report the bug.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Absolutely No.

If you get a fatal error, that's because the JRE has detected a situation where it believes that serious corruption of the JRE data structures has occurred; e.g. the heap has been corrupted.

There is no way to get the JRE to keep going with potentially corrupted state.  And it would be a bad idea to try to anyway.

---

You need to find and fix the problems in your C / C++ code that is causing these crashes.  If that is too hard then:

- recode the native code in Java and ditch the C / C++ versions, or
- turn the C / C++ code into a free-standing application, and run it using `System.exec()` ... or whatever.

(Or since you are running the JVM inside the C / C++ application, get the latter to launch a separate JVM instead.)

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen C pointed out, you should try to FIX the crashes, instead of ignoring them and looking the other way.

But in case the crashes are out of your scope (a buggy library, for example), you can rewrite your application to start from Java. The Java program will do nothing else than invoke C++ app through JNI, having the C++ call in native code wrapped in a try/catch block. In case you expect an exception (a memory Access violation, for example), just catch it and do nothing.

The code example can be seen in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/918891/1043352