# Predictable exit code of crashed process in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, crash, exit-code

For a process exiting normally in Windows, the exit code of the process is generally either the return value from `main`, or the exit code passed to `std::exit`. `%ERRORLEVEL%` can then be used to query the exit code, and that can be used to determine whether the program executed either correctly, or there were some exceptional inputs/failures that indicate a particular problem (application specific).

However, I'm interested in the exit code if the process crashes. Take a very simple example program:

```
int main()
{
    int * a = nullptr;
    *a = 0xBAD;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this and run in Windows, on the command line I get:

```
MyCrashProgram.exe -> crashes
echo %ERRORLEVEL%  -> -1073741819
```

The exit code is consistently this number. Which leads me to several questions:

- Was the exit code `-1073741819` somehow predicable, based on the invalid write crash?
- If so, is there some way to determine the type of crash, based on the exit code?
- Does this change with the compiler used (I used MSVC 2012)?
- Does this change with the version of Windows being used (I used Win10 TP)?
- Does this change with the architecture (eg. x64 - I used Win32)?

Note, I am not interested in how to modify the program to catch the exception. I am interested in classifying crashes that can happen in existing programs, that I may not be able to modify.

Comment: looks to be a standard "STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION" error.

Comment: See `ntstatus.h` in the SDK for more information about status codes.  By convention, processes that exit cleanly return either 0, 1, or a Win32 error code (which are all small positive numbers) so an exit code with the top bit set usually means a status code, typically because of an unhandled exception.  In particular `0xCnnnnnnn` is almost always a status code.   (However, a process *can* return any exit code it likes.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment about `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`, led me to the documentation on [`GetExceptionCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679356(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The return value identifies the type of exception. The following table identifies the exception codes that can occur due to common programming errors. These values are defined in WinBase.h and WinNT.h.

`EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` maps to `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` in the list that follows. All exceptions in the list prefixed with `STATUS` are directly defined to exception codes prefixed with `EXCEPTION`. Following the documentation to [`RaiseException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680552(v=vs.85).aspx), it explains the process of attempting to debug the exception when it occurs, the final step being:

> If the process is not being debugged, or if the associated debugger does not handle the exception, the system provides default handling based on the exception type. For most exceptions, the default action is to call the ExitProcess function.

So to answer my questions:

- Yes, the exit code was predicatble, it maps to `EXCEPTION_STATUS_VIOLATION`.
- Other types of errors would map to other common exception codes. However, with a call to RaiseException with an arbitrary exception code (which was unhandled), the exit code of the process could be anything
- The exit code is dependent on the Windows SDK, not the compiler, executing Windows version or architecture. Although this could theoretically change with newer Windows SDKs, that is highly unlikely for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a related [short blog post by Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110519-00/?p=10623) (emphasis mine):

> There is no standard for process exit codes. You can pass anything you
>   want to Exit­Process, and that's what Get­Exit­Code­Process will give
>   back. The kernel does no interpretation of the value. If youw want
>   code 42 to mean "Something infinitely improbable has occurred" then
>   more power to you.
>
> There is a convention, however, that an exit code of zero means
>   success (though what constitutes "success" is left to the discretion
>   of the author of the program) and a nonzero exit code means failure
>   (again, with details left to the discretion of the programmer). Often,
>   higher values for the exit code indicate more severe types of failure.
>   The command processor ERROR­LEVEL keyword was designed with these
>   convention in mind.
>
> There are cases where your process will get in such a bad state that a
>   component will take it upon itself to terminate the process. For
>   example, if a process cannot locate the DLLs it imports from, or one
>   of those DLLs fails to initialize, **the loader will terminate the
>   process and use the [status code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113996)** as the process exit code. **I believe
>   that when a program crashes due to an unhandled exception, the
>   exception code is used as the exit code.**
>
> A customer was seeing their program crash with an exit code of 3 and
>   couldn't figure out where it was coming from. They never use that exit
>   code in their program. Eventually, the source of the magic number 3
>   was identified: **The C runtime abort function terminates the process
>   with exit code 3**.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no mean a comprehensive answer but rather a few hints so that you can move forward.

I think there is no way to distinguish all the possible cause of crash automatically. To do that you would have to catch the error yourself and provide your own exit code

In order to catch all the possible (catchable) errors, you have to setup both exception and signal handlers.
This is because access violations are exceptions under windows and signal (SIGSEV) under linux.

See this question for the fine details about the different kinds of errors on windows:
[Catching access violation exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457577/catching-access-violation-exceptions)

Here is another thread for [signal handling on linux](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/16430/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I updated the question to state that I'm not interested in modifying the program, I'm only interested in classifying crashes that happen.