# Is segfault guaranteed when dereferencing null pointer (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, null

In the C/C++ code below

```
int * a = malloc(N * sizeof(int)); // suppose return value is NULL
a[2] = 1;
```

In the case where malloc returns `NULL`, do I have a guarantee that segfault will occur or is the behavior unpredictable?

Comment: Depends on the environment. On a PC and most operating systems, you'll get a segfault. On an embedded system, you may not get a segfault.

Comment: No, it is not guaranteed.

Comment: @rcgldr: Considering "most operating systems" are for small embedded devices which don't provide any safety for memory accesses, this is wrong. And even on typical PC OSes, there is no guarantee UB results in an instant crash or specifically a SEGFAULT.

Comment: On a sidenote: `NULL` is a macro. Macros cannot be returned by function nor be passed to functions due to their nature. You mean a _null pointer_, which is not necessarily the same as whatever the macro `NULL` is substituted with.

Answer (score 16):

In a word, no.

To quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer):

> Dereferencing the NULL pointer typically results in an attempted read
>   or write from memory that is not mapped - triggering a segmentation
>   fault or access violation. This may represent itself to the developer
>   as a program crash, or be transformed into an exception that can be
>   caught. **There are, however, certain circumstances where this is not
>   the case**. For example, in x86-real mode, the address 0000:0000 is
>   readable and usually writable, hence dereferencing the null pointer is
>   a perfectly valid but typically unwanted action that may lead to
>   undefined but non-crashing behaviour in the application. Note also
>   that there are occasions when dereferencing the NULL is intentional
>   and well defined; for example BIOS code written in C for 16-bit
>   real-mode x86 devices may write the IDT at physical address 0 of the
>   machine by dereferencing a NULL pointer for writing. **It is also
>   possible for the compiler to optimize away the `NULL` pointer
>   dereference, avoiding a segmentation fault but causing other undesired
>   behavior**...
>
> In C, the behavior of dereferencing a null pointer is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#c-std).

Also check out this [wild example](https://8thlight.com/blog/dariusz-pasciak/2012/07/03/dereferencing-null-pointer-without-a-seg-fault.html) of a null class pointer dereferenced, but which still works just fine.

Basically, **don't do this**, but then you knew that :)

Answer (score 6):

A segfault is **not** guaranteed by the C standard.

Dereferencing an invalid pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 4):

You do not have any guarantee; dereferencing a null pointer is [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). It will *probably* result in a segfault, unless you have certain optimizations turned on or are compiling on a weird platform, in which case it might start executing some other function with effectively random arguments, generate some other error, grab some value out of memory, or [make demons fly out of your nose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon), or skip that line entirely. The *only* one of those which I’d even be surprised by is the next-to-last.

In more detail:

- With certain optimizations, the compiler might detect that you’re
  trying to dereference `NULL`, decide “that isn’t allowed, so that
  code path can never happen”, and get rid of the usual function
  cleanup code; this would result in your program sliding into whatever
  function happens to be next in the output binary.
- If the linker doesn’t put a function next but some other type of value, it might try to execute *that*, which will either result in a problem because it generated an illegal instruction, or a problem because that other object might be marked non-executable by the operating system.
- Some embedded systems don’t have virtual memory, so actually have some values at memory address zero and will happily give you whatever happens to be there.
- To the best of my knowledge, nasal demons would require hardware support which most computers don’t provide, so they’re an unlikely result. If it happens, though, don’t say you weren’t warned.
- As pointed out by @hvd in the comments, the compiler might just skip the line as a dead store.

---

If for some reason you want to generate a segfault, a much better way to do that is with

```
kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV);
```

(after including the appropriate headers). This sends the segfault signal without any actual segmentation violation. If you do want to *actually commit* a segmentation violation, you’re best bet is to map and then unmap some page (this is OS-dependent) and then try to access a pointer into that page.

Comment: In this case, I think a slightly more plausible optimisation is simply that the compiler notices the store will never be followed by a load, so is pointless and can be removed. Since the store then never happens, no segfault.

Comment: @hvd Maybe, but there are times that Clang does remove the end of a function like that. It might only be with `__builtin_unreachable`, though.

Comment: Yeah, the type of optimisation you described does happen, it's just more often when other optimisations prove that in a particular code path, the pointer value is *guaranteed* to be null, from my experience. In the OP's code, the store is to `malloc`'s allocated memory and the compiler will need to allow for the possibility that `malloc` succeeds. :)

Comment: @hvd Yeah, I was assuming that it was just a motivating example. When I explicitly [try this](https://godbolt.org/g/2eE2QZ) (C++, because Compiler Explorer doesn’t support just C), Clang generates an invalid opcode when I assign to a null pointer, but if I change the `[0]` to `[2]`, it tries storing 17 to the address 0x8. If I add `__builtin_unreachable();`, it deletes all the code for `main`. But since it’s undefined behavior you of course can’t count on that.

Comment: *If you do want to actually commit a segmentation violation, you’re best bet is to map and then unmap some page* And even that might get you a `SIGBUS` instead of a `SIGSEGV` if you do it the "wrong" way.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not guaranteed.

For example, what if you run this (evil) code prior to your example:

```
mmap( ( void *) 0, ( size_t ) 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, -1, 0 );
```

That maps an anonymous page with read/write permissions at address `0`.

Comment: This segfaulted when I ran it on Clang-7.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick  Did you check the return value from `mmap()`?

Comment: No. How should I check it?

Answer (score 1):

No, the program is not guaranteed to segfault. [Dereferencing a pointer](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p4) to which an invalid value has been assigned is [undefined behaviour](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p2), and the standard clearly says that undefined behaviour imposes no requirements. It *may* terminate program execution but it does not have to; it may even ignore the situation completely:

> **3.4.3 undefined behavior**
>
> 1 behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct
>   or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no
>   requirements
>
> 2 NOTE Possible **undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation
>   completely** with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation
>   or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
>   environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to
>   terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
>   diagnostic message).