# Why do I get a segmentation fault error with this recursive function?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

1. 

```
void displayAllTVShowsOfActor(TVShow* root, string actor) {
    string *a = root->actor;
    if (root != NULL) {
        while (*a != "NULL") {
          if (*a == actor)
          {
            cout << root->name << endl; 
          }
          cout << "here";
          a = (a+1); 
        }
        displayAllTVShowsOfActor(root->left, actor);
        displayAllTVShowsOfActor(root->right, actor);
    }
   }
```

2. 

```
 void displayAllTVShowsOfActor(TVShow* root, string actor) {
    string *a;
    if (root != NULL) {
       a = root->actor;
        while (*a != "NULL") {
          if (*a == actor)
          {
            cout << root->name << endl; 
          }
          cout << "here";
          a = (a+1); 
        }
        displayAllTVShowsOfActor(root->left, actor);
        displayAllTVShowsOfActor(root->right, actor);
    }
   }
```

The 1st one causes Segmentation Fault Error but if I move the first line to be after the if-statement like I did in the 2nd one, it works. What is causing the segmentation fault error?

Comment: Obviously, when `root` is `null`, `root->actor` will lead to _undefined behavior_, and in most cases you will get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code it seemed to throw segfault because the root might be null.

In C, dereferencing null pointer is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Related: [Dereferencing null pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104370/is-segfault-guaranteed-when-dereferencing-null-pointer-c-c)