# How to stop C++ app from crashing when an Access Violation exception happens in a C# function?

Tags: c++, mono

I am building a C++ application that uses Mono to load in C# code and execute it from within C++. I have a `MonoMethod*` to a C# function that can have code that may cause an Access Violation exception to happen, which obviously makes the application crash.

However, what I would need to happen is instead to somehow catch this exception and pause the code execution, handle the AV, and then continue the code safely.

Is there any way to achieve this? Preferably without libraries, and a solution that will either work on both Windows and Linux (I target both OSs), or a solution for Windows and Linux separately.

I tried using the [try-except statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/try-except-statement?view=msvc-170) from Microsoft (running on Windows, obviously), and even literally copy and pasting the example code didn't work. The application crashed in both Debug and Release.

I also tried the Signal Handler from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457577/), but none of them worked, no matter what configuration I used.

I tried running both on Windows, so maybe the second one would work on Linux, but I haven't tested that as I want to find a solution for Windows first.

Comment: May be related: [pointers validity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551069/testing-pointers-for-validity-c-c)

Comment: You could execute it in a separate process wait for the process to die.

Comment: Letting an exception cross language boundaries is *undefined behavior*.  Just don't do it to begin with.  The C# code has no concept of the outside environment that is running it, and so has no guarantee that such an environment can ever handle any exception that it throws across the boundary.  You need to handle the exception in the same environment that threw it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but I need to, the C# code is written by users and instead of the application crashing whenever they make a small mistake, I want to warn them and stop the execution of the C# class so no issues happen there.

Comment: Sorry, but what you are asking for is generally not possible, and certainly not in a portable manner.  You need to handle C# exceptions inside of the C# code, and C++ exceptions inside the C++ code. Let your code crash when your users make mistakes! You actually circumvent OS safeguards/loggers when you try to block their mistakes like this. You *can't* guarantee you handle the crash correctly/successfully, so don't even try.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have thought of that but would unnecesarily complicate my application, and slow it down significantly

Comment: *I have a MonoMethod* to a C# function that can have code that may cause an Access Violation exception to happen* -- What is the reason for the Access Violation?  Maybe concentrate on fixing the issue with the AV?  There is no way I would release a program where I'm crossing my fingers that it doesn't crash, knowing full well it may/will crash at any moment.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am working on a game engine and the C# function is written by the users of the engine, a case where an AV could happen is they simply forgot to set a field from within the editor, and now the entire editor crashes due to a small mistake. I know for a fact that Unity somehow handles this because their engine doesn't crash when I do such a mistake like that.

Comment: A crash is a result of undefined behavior. This means that the process is not any known, controlled, predictable state. As such, you have no guarantees whatsoever that the process could recover, in any way, into a stable, running state.  Somehow trapping an exception of this kind is just as likely to succeed [as successfully herding a hoard of demons that flew out of your nose, back to where they came from](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).